# ArrayList of the different values of an ArrayList using Iterators

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I've been trying to understand how **Iterators** work and in my tests I am getting **java.util.ConcurrentModificationException** plenty of times. For what I've found this happens when the **Iterator** is running through the **ArrayList** and suddenly a change in its values happens. This can also happen when the method that runs the **Iterator** is called in an event handler I think. In my code both happen.

I know I should run code in background threads when calling methods in event handlers, but I would rather not, because we didn't talk about that in the course I am attending (will do if necessary).

Presently I have this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Node {

private ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> different_value = new ArrayList<String>();

private int differentK = 0;

public Node (Tabela table, int column){
    for (int i = 1; i<table.get_numLines(); i++){
        this.value.add(table.out[column][i]);
    }

    Iterator<String> itr = this.value.iterator();
    Iterator<String> finder = this.different_value.iterator();

    if(this.value.size()!=0) this.different_value.add(this.value.get(0));

    while(itr.hasNext()){
        while(finder.hasNext()){
            if(!itr.next().equals(finder.next())){
                this.differentK++;
                this.different_value.add(itr.next());
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("This node has "+this.differentK+" different K");
}
}
```

And I get `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` in `if(!itr.next().equals(finder.next()))`. I know the problem is probably because I am adding values to the `different_value` ArrayList, but what I want to do is iterate the `value` ArrayList and store the different values taken by the previous in the `different_value` ArrayList.

FootNote: I also found that it is not recommended to change values in an ArrayList when using Iterators through that **ArrayList**. Should I use a more simple `foreach:` approach?

Comment: Not only is it "not recommended", it's *not allowed* (as long as you're using the iterators, anyways). And a for-each loop would also fail because those use iterators behind the scenes anyways.

Comment: Long story short, use a `ListIterator`, and make modifications through the iterators, *NOT* by altering the arrays themselves.

Comment: you're making it way to hard for yourself. just use the iterator to iterate over the original list, and add for each instance you encounter something like:

if ( !list2.contains(iterationElement)){
  list2.add(iterationElement);
}

Comment: Thank you all for the fast and great answers. I chose to use a for each String element in this.value, checks if this.different_value.contains that element, and if not it adds it to the list. I didn't know the contains method of ArrayList, this helps a lot. Big thanks particularly @Stultuske. Ended up using iterator implicitly like user3580294 said in for each only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to add element from list1(value) to list2(different_value) if it doesn't exist in list2.

first comment finder iterator

```
//Iterator<String> finder = this.different_value.iterator();
```

Then use other loop instead of iterator for e.g for-loop

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    String current = itr.next();
    boolean exists = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < different_value.size(); i++) {
    if (current.equals(different_value.get(i))) {
        exists = true;
        break;
    }
    }
    if (!exists) {
    different_value.add(current);
    }
}
```

This should solve your porblem. Adding element in list while iterating is not allowed.